# Django-taggit. Multi-tags in a model. Retrieve data

Tags: django, django-taggit

Here is a model with multiple tags in it. How do I retrieve data from tags_en?
**tags.names()** works well but not **tags_en.names()** nor **tags_en.all()**

```
from taggit.models import GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase, TagBase
from taggit_selectize.managers import TaggableManager

class UUIDTaggedItem(GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tags")


class BaseTag (TagBase):
    pass


class UUIDTaggedItemEn (GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, TaggableManager):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(BaseTag)


class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True, through=UUIDTaggedItem)
    tags_en = TaggableManager(blank=True, through=UUIDTaggedItemEn)
```

Error message is:

> FieldError at /admin/item/item/
>
> Cannot resolve keyword 'None' into field. Choices are: category, id,
>   item, name, slug, taggroup, uuidtaggeditemen

Answer (score 2):

first you should add a Manager attribute to the other class like

```
class UUIDTaggedItemEn (GenericUUIDTaggedItemBase, TaggableManager):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(BaseTag)
    objects = = models.Manager()
```

then you can call the use filter like

```
tags_en.objects.filter(id=...)
tags_en.objects.all()
```

the problem is with multiple taggablemanagers you are calling them though other classes and when ou went to receive the objects you need to call those classes. Hope that helped if not leave a comment

Comment: Now it is: '_TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: when you added the objects to the other class did you ./manage.py makemigration and then ./manage.py migrate?

Comment: I recreated tables from scratch. No any issues during makemigrations/migrate.